# How to convert a glob with braces to a regex

Tags: glob

I want to change a glob such as c{at,lif} in to a regex. What would it look like? I've tried using /c[at,lif]/ but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

For Basic GREP operation see f.e. http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html

From http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html:

> If you want to search for the literal text cat or dog, separate both options with a vertical bar or pipe symbol: cat|dog. If you want more options, simply expand the list: cat|dog|mouse|fish.

This suggests the following should work:

```
/c(at|lif)/
```

#### Obligatory What Was Wrong With Yours, Then:

```
/c[at,lif]/
```

The square brackets `[..]` are not used in GREP for grouping, but to define a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). That is, here you create a custom class which allows one of the characters `at,lif`. Thus it matches `ca` or `c,` or `cf` -- but always only one character. Adding a repetition code `c[at,lif]+` only *appears* to work because it will then match both `cat` and `clif`, but also `cilt`, `calf`, and `c,a,t`.